# Escape characters within clickhouse client terminal

Tags: character-encoding, client, xterm, rhel6, clickhouse

I'm using the clickhouse CLI on a XTERM terminal with a bash shell on Redhat EL6 OS.
The output is unreadable due to terminal escape sequences.
For instance:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM system.tables

ââcount()ââ
â      35 â
âââââââââââ

1 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

Things get better when I use the `--format=PrettySpace` option but eventual `NULL` values are still unreadable:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ont_index
FROM port_status_events
WHERE isNull(ont_index) OR (ont_index < 2)
ORDER BY ont_index ASC NULLS FIRST

ââont_indexââ
â      á´ºáµá´¸á´¸ â
â         0 â
â         1 â
âââââââââââââ

3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec. Processed 11.57 thousand rows, 23.13 KB (3.50 million rows/s., 6.99 MB/s.)
```

Is there a way to tell the client I'm using a different type of terminal?

Comment: That's not *terminal escape sequences*, but a mismatch between the character encoding (UTF-8 vs ISO-8859-1, for instance).

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDickey. I changed my PuTTY settings. Now it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

As @Thomas Dickey correctly said, this has nothing to do with terminal escape sequences but with character encoding.
I changed by PuTTY settings to UTF-8 and everything works correctly now.